# Xamarin.Forms - Open file with default app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, maui

I need to open a file from storage. I used `Launcher.OpenAsync()`, but it always tries to open the file in PDF reader. Is there any other way to open a file with default app on Android?

This is the code I have already tried.

```cs
private void OpenDocument(string filePath)
{
    var localFile = "file://" + filePath;
    Launcher.OpenAsync(localFile);
}
```

Comment: If the file is PDF format , it will be an expect result.

Comment: Yes but it does it with every type of file (png, mp3, ...)

Comment: Did you instance other app which can open other type of file?

Comment: You can share the sample and I will check it on my side .

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Upload your sample to github .And don't forget to remove the personal info ,such as password and account ID .

Comment: Umm maybe try `Device.OpenUri`? If I am not wrong it handles most of the scenarios!

Comment: https://github.com/Menelher/NoteApp

Comment: Device.OpenUri works in same way for me

Comment: Thank you guys for help. I just have found solution. I used StartActivity

Comment: You can post the answer and accept it ,which will help more people .

Answer (score 7):

```
string path = "your uri bla-bla-bla";

 Launcher.OpenAsync
                (new OpenFileRequest()
                {
                    File = new ReadOnlyFile(path)
                }
            );
```

Comment: Launcher is part of Xamarin.Essentials, doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios

Comment: This answer works for .Net MAUI too

Comment: It works for .Net MAUI on Windows but it doesn't work for .Net MAUI on MacOS or iOS.